# Evaluating a sum (alternating binomial series with odd denominators)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

How do I evaluate the following sum (for some positive integer $m$)?:
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{m}{{m \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}}$$
After expanding it looks like:
$$S={m \choose 0}-\frac{1}{3}{m \choose 1} + \frac{1}{5}{m \choose 2} - \frac{1}{7}{m \choose 3}+-\dots$$
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum has the integral representation
$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^n\binom mk\int_0^1 x^{2k}\,dx
=\int_0^1(1-x^2)^m\,dx.$$
Letting $y=x^2$ gives
$$\frac12\int_0^1(1-y)^m \frac{dy}{\sqrt y}$$
which can be evaluated in terms of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).